# how to lock content until a specific button is pressed on a css animation using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css-animations

so I am creating a game idea for an assignment, and I wanted to lock the 2nd and 3rd main menu buttons until they have completed the game in order, just to force a little extra structure into how people would use the animation/game, we are using css animation, so everything is on a one page html document and one js file.

here is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Meltdown</title>

        <!-- makes browsers render all elements more consistently. Similar to a CSS reset file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">

        <!-- the main style sheet you should edit -->  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 

        <!-- link to PT-Sans font from google fonts --> 
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- link to local version of jQuery --> 
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Link to javascript file  --> 
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>

        <!-- Link to JQuery Library and UI  -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        

        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- main page wrap for the interactive -->
        <div id="main-container"> 

            <!-- container for all the individual pages -->
            <div class="pages">
                <!-- ========================= INTRO =========================== -->

                <div class="page-intro current">
                        <!--HOME PAGE-->

                        <div class="home-page">
                            <div id="home-img"></div>
                            
                            <div id="volume-slider">
                                <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider">
                              </div>
                                            <!--Trees-->
                
                            <div class="tree"></div>
                            <div class="tree2"></div>
                            <div class="tree3"></div>
                
                                            <!--Title-->
                
                                <div class="title"></div>
                
                                            <!--Steam-->
                
                            <div class="steam"></div>
                
                                            <!--Interacables-->
                
                            <div class="intro-button">START</div>
                
                                            <!--Introduction-->
                
                            <div class="nuclear-icon"></div>
                            <div class="nuclear-icon-two"></div>
                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ========================= MENU =========================== -->

                <div class="page-menu">
                    <h1>Main Menu</h1>
                    <div class="menu1-button button">
                        Start study now!
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu2-button button" disabled>
                        Multiple choice!
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu3-button button" disabled>
                        Fix the circuit!
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- menu page -->

                <!-- ========================= OTHER PAGES =========================== -->
                
                <div class="page-study">
                    <h1>Learning the basics</h1>
                    <div class="p1-button button">
                        Multiple choice!
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-box box1">
                        <h1>Key points</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Circuit diagrams are used to show how electrical <span class="important">components</span> are connected in a <span class="important">circuit.</span></li>
                            <li>Individual circuit components are represented using circuit symbols.</li>
                            <li>Ammeters are used to measure the <span class="important">current</span> flowing through components. Voltmeters are used to measure the <span class="important">potential difference</span> across components.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-box box2">
                        <h2>Circuit symbols</h2>
                        <p>Electrical components, like motors and lamps, can be connected together to form a circuit.</p>
                        <p>A circuit diagram shows how the components are connected.</p>
                        <p>straight lines to show the wires andcircuit symbols to represent each component.</p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="reveal-more">Click me!</button>
                    <div class="text-box box3">
                        <h1>Cells</h1>
                        <p>Cells provide the energy for many electrical devices to function - like torches, mobile phones and laptops. Cells come in different sizes and shapes.</p>
                        <p>The most common type of cell is the electrochemical cell which uses chemical reactions to transfer energy.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-box box4">
                        <h2>Potential Difference</h2>
                        <p>Potential difference is the amount of energy transferred by each unit of charge passing between two points of a circuit.</p>
                        <p>The unit of potential difference is the volt. The symbol for volts is V. A potential difference of 1.5 volts can be written as 1.5 V.</p>
                        <p>Potential difference is also commonly called 'voltage'.</p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="continue-button">Next</button>
                    <div class="p-menu-button button">
                        Go back to menu
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Multiple Choice Page -->

                <div class="page-multiple-choice">
                    <div id="beginning-screen-quiz">
                        <h1 id="heading-quiz">Oh no! it looks like you have been locked out of the computer system. You will have to take this quiz in order to regain access, you must get a score of 60 in order to bypass the security system.</h1>
                        <button id="start-button-quiz">Hack into security</button>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Multiple Choice Quiz</h1>
                    <div class="p2-button button">
                        Fix the circuit
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-menu-button button">
                        Go back to menu
                    </div>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="question">Sample question here</div>
                        <div id="answersAndFeedback">
                            <div id="answer1" class="answer-box">Answer 1</div>
                            <div id="answer2" class="answer-box">Answer 2</div>
                            <div id="answer3" class="answer-box">Answer 3</div>
                            <div id="feedback" class="hidden">Feedback goes here</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="score">0</div>
                        <div id="next-btn" class="hidden">next</div>
                        <div id="game-over" class="hidden">Congratulations! Continue to the next page!</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Circuit Page -->

                <div class="page-circuit">
                    <div id="beginning-screen">
                        <h1 id="heading">Quickly, the reactor has blown a circuit. You are the last chance at saving this power plant, in order to save us all, you have to correctly place all the symbols in the correct slots.</h1>
                        <button id="start-button">Save the Power Plant</button>
                      </div>
                    <h1 id="circuit-text">Fix the circuit</h1>  
                    <div class="p-menu-button button">
                        Go back to menu
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <img id="drag1" src="img/voltmeter.svg" alt="Draggable Image 1">
                        <img id="drag2" src="img/fixed-resistor.svg" alt="Draggable Image 2">
                        <div id="drop">Drop Here</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="container2">
                        <img id="drag3" src="img/bulb.svg" alt="Draggable Image 1">
                        <img id="drag4" src="img/variable-resistor.svg" alt="Draggable Image 2">
                        <div id="drop2">Drop Here</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="container3">
                        <img id="drag5" src="img/battery.svg" alt="Draggable Image 1">
                        <img id="drag6" src="img/closed-switch.svg" alt="Draggable Image 2">
                        <div id="drop3">Drop Here</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="incomplete-circuit">
                      </div>
                      <div id="end-screen">
                        <h1 id="heading">Congratulations, you have finished, you have saved the power plant from exploding! You are a Hero!</h1>
                        <button id="back-to-start-button">Back to Start</button>
                      </div>                      
                </div>
                

            </div> <!-- end of pages -->

            <!-- add any containers here that you don't want to animate when pages transition -->
            <div class="persistent-stuff">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of main container -->
    </body>
</html>
```

so I wanted `<div class="menu2-button button">Multiple choice!</div>` to be locked until the person has gone through the work on the `<div class="page-study">` and pressed the `<div class="p1-button button">Multiple choice!</div>`.
then I also wanted the same with `<div class="menu3-button button">Fix the circuit!</div>` until the button on `<div class="page-multiple-choice">` was pressed which is  `<div class="p2-button button">Fix the circuit</div>`.

here are the current functions that are affillated with these elements.

```
    // --------------------------- Menu Page -------------------------------------

    $('.menu1-button').click(function(){
        transition(".page-study","fade");
    });

    $('.menu2-button').click(function(){
        transition(".page-multiple-choice","fade");
    });

    $('.menu3-button').click(function(){
        transition(".page-circuit","fade");
    });
  

    // --------------------------- Study Page -------------------------------------

    $('.p1-button').click(function(){
        transition(".page-multiple-choice","push-left");
    });

    $('.p2-button').click(function(){
        transition(".page-circuit","push-right");
    });

    $('.p-menu-button').click(function(){
        transition(".page-menu","fade");
    });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated as this is one of the last major things I need to complete in order to finish it :)

I tried adding a class to the button of .disabled, which had onclick=false applied to it, and then a class of .enable which had onclick=true on the buttons, but it ended up blocking me from pressing any of the buttons that were on the screens.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the user's progress inside a variable and then reference it when you need it. There are many ways to go about it. One is shown here: create an array and store the milestones in it (like '`p1`' for when they click the `p1 button` or '`p2`' etc). Then when they click the corresponding `menu button`, just test for the milestone variable as shown. I show an alert so you can see it checking, but the alert isn't neccesary. I also didn't have access to the `transition` function in the code so I put a placeholder function for that - just ignore it in your own code.

```js
let completedArr = []
let transition = () => {} // don't use this, just to prevent errors in the example

$('.menu1-button').click(function() {
  transition(".page-study", "fade");
});

$('.menu2-button').click(function() {
  if (!completedArr.includes('p1')) return alert("not availabled yet");
 transition(".page-multiple-choice", "fade");
});

$('.menu3-button').click(function() {
  if (!completedArr.includes('p2')) return alert("not availabled yet");
  transition(".page-circuit", "fade");
});


// --------------------------- Study Page -------------------------------------

$('.p1-button').click(function() {
  if (!completedArr.includes('p1')) completedArr.push('p1')
  transition(".page-multiple-choice", "push-left");
});

$('.p2-button').click(function() {
  if (!completedArr.includes('p2')) completedArr.push('p2')
  transition(".page-circuit", "push-right");
});

$('.p-menu-button').click(function() {
  transition(".page-menu", "fade");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='p1-button'>p1-button</button>
<button class='p2-button'>p2-button</button>
<button class='p3-button'>p3-button</button>

<hr>
<button class='menu1-button'>menu1-button</button>
<button class='menu2-button'>menu2-button</button>
<button class='menu3-button'>menu3-button</button>
```

Comment: Hi there, so I tried adding this to my code, however when I linked the script into my HTML, it then told me that my draggable attribute that was previously working was no longer working? any idea how I can fix this as we was taught the draggable att for our assignment?

Comment: be sure to: 1. not use the JQUERY script tag I have in my code (at the top), that was just for my example. and 2. not to use the `let transitions = ()...`